# The normal closure of a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm making my first steps in abstract algebra and I was wondering, if there is a technique to determine the normal closure of a given extension, cause all I know is a theoretical definition: $K_n$ is a normal closure of an extension $K/k$ if it's the intersection of all the normal extensions that contain $K$.

> As an application, what is the normal closure of $\mathbb Q(i,j\sqrt[3]{2})$?

thank you for your time

Comment: I suppose by $j$ you denoted a primitive third root of unity.

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All normal extensions are splitting fields and vice versa.

In your particular case you have two algebraic numbers, that is, $i$ and $j\sqrt[3]{2}$. The spliting field of the first is $\mathbb Q(i)$, while of the second is $\mathbb Q(j, \sqrt[3]{2})$. Now take their [compositum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_fields#Compositum_of_fields) and this is the normal closure.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you made explicit what exactly you mean by "glue"... I, for one, don't know!

Comment: So this is the technique we search the algebraic elements that generate the extension, am I right ? and you mean by "glue" them, that the normal closure is $\mathbb Q(i,j,\sqrt[3]{2})$ ?!!

Comment: Did you by any means mean to say that all splitting fields are normal extensions? To me that would seem to be more relevant here.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Actually these are equivalent, isn't it?

Comment: Well if you mean splitting field of an arbitrary collection of polynomials (rather than of one), then yes. So you could say: just take the splitting field of the minimal polynomials over $k$ of all elements in $K$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen That is exactly what I've meant.